# Modify method call if chained

Tags: python

Better to provide an example i guess (a littler bit pseudo-codish...)

```py
from django.db import transaction
from somewhere import some_job
from functools import partial

class Foo:

  def do_something(self, key, value):
    return some_job(key, value)
  
  @property
  def modifier(self):
    pass

f = Foo()
f.do_something(key='a', value=1) -> result

f.modifier.do_something(key='a', value=1) -> transaction.on_commit(partial(do_something, key='a', value=1))
```

Normally if **do_something** is called it would do it regular thing and return some result,
but when it is chained via **modifier** it should return `transaction.on_commit(partial(do_something, key='a', value=1))` instead of regular result. Modifier might be property or something else inside class. Problem is that this insinstance is a singletone and should not be changed permanently as it will be used latelly by other code.

Can not wrap my head around how to do this.
Any ideas?

Comment: `modifier` should return an instance of some other class that wraps `self` and whose `do_something` method delegates to `Foo.do_something`.

Comment: well, now it is looks like descriptor. Also do_something is an example method. It might be few methods needs to be modified. Their names are unknown as they might be defined in subclasses

Comment: Properties *are* descriptors. `f.modifier` just calls `Foo.__dict__['modifier'].__get__(f, Foo)`, which returns whatever the `fget` attribute of the `modifier` object returns when applied to `f`. (Put another way, `f.modifier == Foo.modifier.fget(f)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can have the `modifier` property return a quick-and-dirty wrapper class that implements the method `do_something` *itself* but does something different to the underlying `foo` instance.

```
class Foo:

  def do_something(self, key, value):
    print(f"Called unmodified on {self} :)")

  @property
  def modifier(self):
    return ModifiedFoo(self)


class ModifiedFoo:

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def do_something(self, key, value):
        print(f"Called modified on {self.foo} :)")

f = Foo()
f.do_something(key='a', value=1)
f.modifier.do_something(key='a', value=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Modifier(Foo):
    def do_something(this, key, value):
        transaction.on_commit(partial(super().do_something, key='a', value=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This does modify the `foo` object, but it should work if you change the name for `_lock` so it doesn't collide with other attributes.

```py
from functools import partial

class Foo:
  _lock = False

  def do_something(self, key, value):
    if self._lock:
      transaction.on_commit(partial(some_job, key, value))
      self._lock = False
    else:
      return some_job(key, value)

  def lock(self):
    self._lock = True
    return self

# some mocks
class Transaction:
  @staticmethod
  def on_commit(func):
    print("Transaction commit success.")
    func()

some_job = lambda x, y: print("Some job", x, y)
transaction = Transaction()
# end mocks

foo = Foo()

print(">>> foo.do_something(...)")
foo.do_something('key1', 'value1')
# Some job key1 value1

print(">>> foo.lock().do_something(...)")
foo.lock().do_something('key2', 'value2')
# Transaction commit success.
# Some job key2 value2
```